# Android - GSON lib - Object deserializing Object

Tags: android, deserialization, gson

I use GSON lib to deserialize my objects when I get result from WS. For example my web service response contains :

```
"id" : "myid"
"code" : 200
"data" : can be anything (String, JSONObject, JSONArray...)
```

So here my class :

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private Object id;
    private int code;
    private Object data;
    private String type;

    public MyClass() 
    {
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Object getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Object id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't know which type of data "data" would be, so I used the **Object** type here.

So when I get response I use :

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();        
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

And used this method to convert my class :

```
public <T> T deserialize(Type pClass, JSONObject pJsonObject)
    {
        try
        {
            return gson.fromJson(pJsonObject.toString(), pClass);
        }
        catch (JsonSyntaxException e)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Everything works well. But I have a little problem. "data" field can be everything (a String, an Integer, a JSONObject, ...), and for my example, data is a JSONObject when I get result here. So "data" (which is Object) is a JSONObject, but converted into a LinkedTreeMap automatically here and not a JSONObject, so when I want to parse "data", I have a CastException :/

So the real problem here is if the user has sent a JSONObject to the API and I get this result when I call web service, GSON converts this JSONObject into a LinkedTreeMap, but I want to retrieve the same type that has been sent by the user.

Is it possible ?

Thanks to all !

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Generic Model Class where "data" would be a String or Json Object..

It will help if you definitely know what is the "data" going to be, say for eg. it'l be a json object..then:  (or can keep it as String and then check through code and map it accordingly)

```
private String id;
private int code;
private JsonObject data;
private String type;
```

And can use *Annotation*, from Gson lib, in the model class:

```
@SerializedName("responseVariableStringHere")  
private String responseVariable;
```

Then,

```
modelClassObject = gson.fromJson(responseContentString,ModelClass.class);
```

after that,

```
JsonObject job = modelClassObject.getData();
```

And repeat the mapping process..this time with the model class object which "data" has in response

```
objectFromData = gson.fromJson(job.get("tagfromtheJsonObject"), ObjectFromData.class);
```

Can avoid writing the:

```
public <T> T deserialize(Type pClass, JSONObject pJsonObject)
```